# reduceByKey not working as expected when keys are of type bitarray

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Following is the code that I am trying out in pyspark shell.

```
from bitarray import bitarray
a = bitarray('0') * 5
b = bitarray('1') * 5
c = [a.copy() for x in range(3)]
d = [b.copy() for x in range(5)]
e = c + d
rdd = sc.parallelize(e).map(lambda x : (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y : x + y).collect()
print(rdd)
```

Expected:

```
[(bitarray('11111'), 5), (bitarray('00000'), 3)
```

Actual output:

```
[(bitarray('11111'), 1), (bitarray('00000'), 1), (bitarray('11111'), 1), (bitarray('11111'), 1), (bitarray('00000'), 1), (bitarray('11111'), 1), (bitarray('00000'), 1), (bitarray('11111'), 1)]
```

Why isn't spark engine able to differentiate between the different bitarray values?

Comment: What is the hash and equals of the a[0] and a[1]? I believe that shows through id(a[0]), but am not really a python guy

Comment: Don't think this is possible, see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29725381/4964651

Comment: Thanks @mtoto! That verifies the problem. Hash has to be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of circumventing the issue would convert all the `bitarray` into bytes using the `tobytes`. Also, cause of the problem is discussed in the link provided by @mtoto which is bitarray does not maintain the hash invariant.

```
from bitarray import bitarray

def back2Bit(U):
        res = bitarray()
        res.frombytes(U)
        return res

a = bitarray('0') * 5
b = bitarray('1') * 5
c = [a.copy() for x in range(3)]
d = [b.copy() for x in range(5)]
e = c + d
rdd = sc.parallelize([x.tobytes() for x in e]).map(lambda x : (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y : x + y).collect()
rdd = [(back2Bit(x[0]), x[1]) for x in rdd]
```